# Firebase : What happens to a database connection after it has been used

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was just wondering if there isn't a need to close the `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` instance after it has been used or free whatever resources used by this.

I use the **instance** as follows.

```
  String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
  DatabaseReference DB  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  for (final Message M : Messages) {
     if (!M.getSender().equals(UID) && !M.getLocal() && !M.getRead()) {
        DatabaseReference r = DB.child("chat/messages/" + M.getMessageid()+"/read");
        r.setValue(true, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(DatabaseError e, DatabaseReference dbr) {
              if (e != null) {
                 System.out.println("Message Read could not be updated" + e.getMessage());
              } else {
                 System.out.println("Message Read updated" + M.getMessageid());
              }
           }
        });
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first start interacting with the Firebase Database, it opens a socket connection between the app and the Firebase servers. From that moment on, all traffic between the app and the database goes over that same socket.

If there are no active listeners and no write operations for a certain amount of time, the Firebase Database client will automatically close the connection. Of course it will then re-open the connection when you attach a listener or perform a write again.

If you want more fine-grained control over the connection, you can explicitly manage this by calling `goOffline()` and `goOnline()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state